# Python isub inside a lambda

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax, lambda

Why does `left = lambda: cursor = cursor - 1` work while `left = lambda: cursor -= cursor` gives me a syntax error?

Is there a problem with in place subtracting inside a `lambda`?

EDIT:
A bit of context.
I am trying to have a class with a member such as:

```
self.instructions = {
            "0": lambda: self.tape[self.cursor] = 0   
            "1": lambda: self.tape[self.cursor] = 1
            "L": lambda: self.cursor -= 1
            "R": lambda: self.cursor += 1
            "HALT" = lambda: self.halted = True]
        }
```

How do I make this work?

Comment: What do you wanna? Is cursor a global variable? What's the purpose of left?

Comment: Cursor is a class member. When left is called, it must be decremented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The straight-forward solution:

```
def zero(self):
    self.tape[self.cursor] = 0

def one(self):
    self.tape[self.cursor] = 1

def left(self):
    self.cursor -= 1

def right(self):
    self.cursor += 1

def halt(self):
    self.halted = True

self.instructions = {
        "0": self.zero(),  
        "1": self.one(),
        "L": self.left(),
        "R": self.right(),
        "HALT": self.halt()
        }
```

Not the best design IMO, but it should work.

Comment: It's what I've finally used. What design would you otherwise implement?

Comment: Instead of a class dictionary attribute, a class method like `def instructions(self, input)` is more intuitive, IMHO.  If I saw this my first question would be "why use a dictionary?"  Of course, if there is a good reason to do it, then you should.

Comment: That would obly me to use a elsif tree, and that is something to be avoided, at least from my point of view. Flat is better than nested.

Answer (score 5):

A `lambda` expression is a shortcut for a function that only returns a value:

```
func = lambda x: x - 1
```

is roughly the same as

```
def func(x):
    return x - 1
```

Neither of your examples work, because assignment is not an expression in Python like it is in some other languages (particularly the ones that resemble C). That is, `cursor = cursor - 1` can't be in a `lambda` any more than `cursor -= 1` can be. Neither can go in a `return` statement either.

Comment: Great insight, @kindall. Very helpful indeed.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `lambda` expressions with the wrong syntax. Take a look at this example:

```
>>> decrement = lambda x: x - 1
>>> decrement(24)
23
```